# How to dynamically add method to class with `functools.partial()`

Tags: python, functools, partial-application

I am having trouble with the right incantation to get a dynamic method added to a class using `functools.partial` in the following situation.  The following has a `Creator` class to which I want to add a `create_someclass` method, which is partially parameterized by the `creator` class state.

```
import functools

class Creator:
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params

class Stitch:
    __tablename__ = 'stitch'
    def __init__(self, params, name):
        self.name = name
        self.params = params

def create(self, clz, *args, **kwargs):
    return clz(self.params, *args, **kwargs)

for clazz in [Stitch]:
    setattr(Creator, 'create_%s' % clazz.__tablename__, functools.partial(create, clz=clazz))

creator = Creator('params')

# Neither of these work, but I'd like either one -- preferably the first one.

stitch = creator.create_stitch('myname')
# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'params'

stitch = creator.create_stitch(name='myname')  
# TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem for making `partial` for class methods, so in Python 3.4 we introduced `partialmethod` as the alternative. The way that works is the following:

```
import functools

class Creator:
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params

class Stitch:
    __tablename__ = 'stitch'
    def __init__(self, params, name):
        self.name = name
        self.params = params

def create(self, clz, *args, **kwargs):
    return clz(self.params, *args, **kwargs)

for clazz in [Stitch]:
    setattr(Creator, 'create_%s' % clazz.__tablename__, functools.partialmethod(create, clz=clazz))
    # use partialmethod instead here

creator = Creator('params')

stitch = creator.create_stitch(name='myname')  
# works!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `create` is a member function of Stitch (despite your bad indentation: `create` accesses the member variable `params` of `Stitch`), so you would need an object of type `Stitch` to use with `create`, which would then also be passed as the first argument to `create`. It would work like this:

```
import functools


class Creator:
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params

class Stitch:
    __tablename__ = 'stitch'
    def __init__(self, params, name):
        self.name = name
        self.params = params

    def create(self, clz, *args, **kwargs):
        return clz(self.params, *args, **kwargs)


creator = Creator('params')
stitch1 = Stitch('pp', 'my_name')
print("stitch1= ", stitch1)

for clazz in [Stitch]:
    setattr(Creator, 'create_%s' % clazz.__tablename__, functools.partial(stitch1.create, clazz))

stitch = creator.create_stitch('myname')
print("stitch= ", stitch)
```